# Cannot dispatch action after reading from async storage

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, asyncstorage

This is my code

```
export const getAsyncStorage = () => async dispatch => {
    try {
        const asyncStorage = await AsyncStorage.getItem('settings');
        const asyncStorageObject = asyncStorage != null ? JSON.parse(asyncStorage) : null;
        console.log(asyncStorageObject) // this logs an object, as expected
        dispatch({ type: GET_ASYNC_STORAGE, payload: asyncStorageObject })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error in getAsyncStorage writing to AsyncStorage', e)
    }
}
```

This is the error I get

> Error in getAsyncStorage writing to AsyncStorage ReferenceError: payload is not defined

Why does it throw "Payload not defined"? That does not make any sense to me. Deleting this line

`dispatch({ type: GET_ASYNC_STORAGE, payload: asyncStorageObject })`

solves it. When I change this line

`dispatch({ type: GET_ASYNC_STORAGE, payload: asyncStorageObject })`

to

`dispatch({ type: GET_ASYNC_STORAGE, foo: asyncStorageObject })`

I still get the same `payload` message... Not sure what that means.
Here is how I write to `AsyncStorage`:

```
export const writeAsyncStorage = () => async dispatch => {
    try {
        const settings = {...}
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('settings', JSON.stringify(settings));
        dispatch({ type: WRITE_ASYNC_STORAGE, payload: true, })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error in onIntroDone writing to AsyncStorage', e)
    }
}
```

And the `reducer`

```
import {
    GET_ASYNC_STORAGE,
    ...
} from '../constants/actions';

const initialState = {
    ...
    asyncStorage: {}
};

const settings = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        ...
        case GET_ASYNC_STORAGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                asyncStorage: payload.asyncStorage
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default settings;
```

Comment: you should debug the code to find out which line of code is causing the error

Comment: @AHMEDSAJJAD it is that one `dispatch({ type: WRITE_ASYNC_STORAGE, payload: true, })`

Comment: @Stophface Try to `console.log(settings)` ... I don know what's init ... make sure it doesn't include any `promises` (if it's not static)

Comment: Did you try logging your result with `JSON.stringify` just to ensure that you don't get a lazy evaluation in your console?

Comment: @Icepickle Not sure what lazy evaluation is, but when I stringify it, it looks just the same. The debugger does not recognize it as an object, but I can parse it as an object. Changing this `dispatch({ type: GET_ASYNC_STORAGE, payload: asyncStorageObject })` to `dispatch({ type: GET_ASYNC_STORAGE, foo: asyncStorageObject })` still gives the same error... Not sure where `payload` is undefined.

Comment: Can you paste in the code for the reducer that is triggered on `GET_ASYNC_STORAGE`

Comment: `asyncStorage: payload.asyncStorage` <--- .... it's `action.payload`

Comment: @DehandeCroos Ah now I have seen it. Oh my... I forgot the `ACTION.payload.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your reducer, you have to type `action.payload` instead of `payload.asyncStorage`